# Does a focus have to be exact or is there some leeway?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spell-components

There are many kinds of components to spells. [Scrying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying) requires a Focus of a silver mirror worth 1,000 gp. So its a reflective item, made of silver, which costs 1,000+ gp.

Could that item be replaced with a mithral shield that has been polished? Mithral counts as silver (at least for overcoming DR), and a mithral shield costs more than 1000gp. So it can meet some of those requirements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The GM determines if an alternative to a necessary focus is close enough

The game expects a caster to have the focus the spell requires or the spell can't be cast. There's no mechanic for substituting a focus that's simply *similar* for a *required* focus. The rules don't include, for example, making a [Spellcraft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/spellcraft) skill check or [Knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/knowledge) (arcana) skill check to *improvise* a focus from something inappropriate.

So, when the spell [*scrying*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying) demands as a focus "a silver mirror worth 1,000 gp," the DM must rule if, instead, a 2-lb. block of polished [mithral](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials#TOC-Mithral) is sufficient to cast the spell. Likewise, when the spell [*create pit*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-pit) demands a "miniature shovel costing 10 gp," the DM must rule if, instead, a masterwork Medium [monk's spade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/monk-s-spade) is sufficient. (After all, it's miniature for a giant!)

In other words, steel yourself for disappointment, and be thankful that magic is unpredictable if the spell works anyway.

Comment: Just a minor clarification request - wasn't it "worth *at least* X gp"?

Comment: @Mołot The linked spells don't mention *at least*.

Comment: Oh OK. I was *sure* you can use more expensive focuses / components, but wasn't able to find an actual rule for it. If there isn't any, then my bad. Of course, "This mirror is worth too much! Let's scratch it a bit to make it worth less!" would be ridiculous :D

Comment: Considering the process to create mirrors, a "polished" silver/mithral shield will hardly, if ever, be reflective enough to see as clearly as a mirror. The most polished alumnium images i could find were at least 50% blurry at best. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror#Types_of_glass_mirrors

Comment: @Mołot Magic demands precision craftsmanship, I guess? (I do find it interesting that the mirror must be *worth* 1,000 gp yet the shovel must *cost* 10 gp. The mirror's a pain to acquire, but your buddy can break his shovel over his knee ("It's miniature now"), sell it to you for 10 gp, and — *voila!* — you have a *create pit* focus.)

Comment: It's a completely different story if this shield had the Reflecting special ability: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/reflecting

Comment: Or target of the Mirror Polish spell: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mirror-polish

Comment: We eventually house-ruled spell components and focii because this is the kind of minutae that drags down the game sometimes. We ruled that as long as you have your gear, it's always assumed you have any component of minor cost (i.e. less than 100GP) and that for any component 100GP and up, you can substitute any similar item of that value or greater. For example, don't have 5000GP diamond for raise dead? Substitute 5000GP worth of other gems and so forth. Made our game so much better for spellcasters.

Answer (score 0):

### No. It has to be exact.

There is no mechanic that allows for a material component substitution for similar priced items, unless exceptions are given on those descriptions. Spells are created following a precise formula to obtain precise results, and if that formula is not followed to precision, the spell **fizzles**.

So, for the core rulebook spell [Scrying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying), you need a Silver Mirror worth 1,000 gp. If this mirror is worth 5,000 gp, its either too big for the spell, or made of different materials, or too good for the spell to work. If it's worth less, it's simply not big or good enough.

Now, there are exceptions to this rule, such as replacing your divine focus by a shield with the divine symbol of your god on it, or a tattoo. Or [specific](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/voidstick) magic [items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/pale-orange-rhomboid) that allow you to [replace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/seer-s-tea) the [material focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/minor-artifacts/dark-grimoire) of a spell.

An exception to this could be the [Mirror Polish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mirror-polish) spell, which turns a metal item into a reflective mirror. Being a 1th level spell, that is much more readily available than mithral, the shield must be worth exactly 1,000 gp though, which is unlikely to happen, and thus the spell would fizzle.

Another example was published on the [Hungry are the Dead](http://paizo.com/products/btpy85en?Pathfinder-Module-D4-Hungry-Are-the-Dead) (3.5 module by paizo) as the [Eye of Scrying](http://archivesofnethys.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Eye%20of%20Scrying), which sadly never got converted to pathfinder.

If we look at the [process to create mirrors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror#Types_of_glass_mirrors), a "polished" silver/mithral shield will hardly, if ever, be reflective enough to see as clearly as a mirror. The most polished metals i could find on a quick search were blurred and not perfectly reflective. Even using [modern techniques](http://www.instructables.com/answers/How-can-I-sand-stainless-steel-down-to-a-flawless-/) that's not something easily done.

### Research a New Spell

You could [research](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/downtime#TOC-Research-a-Spell) your own version of [Scrying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying) that allows it being used on any surface reflective enough to be used as a mirror, assuming you have the time and *your GM allows it*.

So, now with your own version of the spell, you could even use a shield with the [Reflective](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/reflecting) special ability. Or item targeted by [Mirror Polish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mirror-polish).